# How to replace string inside special characters like /85486/ using bat programming?

Tags: batch-file

I want to get a string inside special characters `/` in the 2nd line and replace into the 1st line next to `NCLR`.

INPUT:

```
:61:1508080808C19476,00NCLROTHERS
 SUDHAKAR H SHETTY/526532/COB
:86:THANE - GOKHALE ROAD
SUDHAKAR H SHETTY/526532/COB
:61:1508080808C2470,00NCLROTHERS
 SHARADCHANDRA L/000207/HDF
:86:THANE - GOKHALE ROAD
SHARADCHANDRA L/000207/HDF
```

OUTPUT:

```
:61:1508080808C19476,00NCLR526532
 SUDHAKAR H SHETTY/526532/COB
:86:THANE - GOKHALE ROAD
SUDHAKAR H SHETTY/526532/COB
:61:1508080808C2470,00NCLR000207
 SHARADCHANDRA L/000207/HDF
:86:THANE - GOKHALE ROAD
SHARADCHANDRA L/000207/HDF
```

I hope now you can understand what I am trying to say. In `output` just get a string in `:61` below line inside `/526532/` and replace in `:61` the 1st line in `OTHERS` string

- BEFORE (INPUT): `00NCLROTHERS`
- AFTER (OUTPUT): `00NCLR526532`

Comment: What have you tried? What are the specific coding problems you need help with? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: So apparently this is a `do-it-all-for-me` question. FWIW I'd do it in a text editor with regexp search&replace as `(:\d+:[^\n]+?NCLR)[^\n]+?\n([^\n]+?/)([^\n]+?)(/[^\n]+?)\n` to `\1\3\n\2\3\4\n`.

Comment: http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.Replace

Answer (score 0):

Simple using [JREPL.BAT - a hybrid JScript/batch regular expression text processing utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044). The utility is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward, no 3rd party compiled executables required.

Below are two equal length solutions that give identical results. One uses a look ahead search, the other doesn't. Both require the `/M` option to search across multiple lines:

```
jrepl "^(:61:.*NCLR).*(?=\r?\n.*/(.*)/)" "$1$2" /m /f test.txt /o -
```

or

```
jrepl "^(:61:.*NCLR).*(\r?\n.*/(.*)/)" "$1$3$2" /m /f test.txt /o -
```

Use `CALL JREPL` if you put the command within a batch script.